# CSS Drop "down" menu side by side

Tags: html, css

i dont have much experience in html + css however e do have google so, easy to lean, but sometimes things goes hard. 
I am trying do do my own portfolio where the fist page display only my logo and a drop down menu whit two language. 
It is on left bottom and when mouse is over its displays up but i wanted display to the right side by side.

- Portuguese
- English
- Language

But i want like this.

- Language - English - Portuguese

html:

```
<nav > 
<ul >
    <li><a href=""><img src="image/language.png" alt="English - UK" width="229" height="37" /></a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="HTML.html"><img src="image/english.png" alt="English - UK" width="139" height="37" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="image/portugues.png" alt="Portugues - BR" width="139" height="37" /></a></li>             

        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
   nav ul ul {
   display: none;
}


 nav ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
}

nav ul {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 300px 50px;        
    margin-left: -10px; 
padding: 10px;    
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table; 
bottom: 100%;

}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}   

    nav ul li {
    float: left;

}

nav ul li:hover {


}

nav ul li:hover a {
/*color: #fff;*/
}

nav ul li a {
 padding: 0px;
}

nav ul ul {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 139px 37px;
position: absolute; left: 13%;
padding: 1px;   
}

nav ul ul li {
float: none;        
position: relative;     
}

nav ul ul li a {
padding: 15px 43px;
/*color: #fff;*/
}   

nav ul ul li a:hover {

}

nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:50;
}
```

I really appreciate any help

Thank you very much

**UPDATE**: Here is a print screen with the way i did and the way i need! 
http://i395.photobucket.com/albums/pp32/jh4ck/imagen1.jpg

Comment: Please create JSfiddle. It would be much easy to debug. JSfiddle.net

Comment: Please provide us with the full image URL's instead of image/*.png

Comment: @Daan
i didn't understand. U want like C:\wamp\www\h.toffanelo\image
Like this? Sorry

Comment: Ah you have it on a local server, well you should try to upload it somewhere, and give us the link to the uploaded image.

Comment: actually i am looking for a place to host it. I have a print showing how does it work but as i am new here im not allowed to post any photos!

Comment: @Daan I got a print just to have a look.  http://i395.photobucket.com/albums/pp32/jh4ck/imagen1.jpg

Comment: You can upload it to photobucket, instead of uploading the printscreen you can upload the pictures to there. Then edit your code here so people can help you better. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to

```
ul ul li{display: inline-block}
```

or

```
ul ul li{display: inline}
```

Comment: u mean where 
nav ul ul li { float: none; position: relative;}? I did but doesn't  work

Comment: You also had some redundant </li>, which I removed from your post. Have you removed them from your html?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could do with the code you provided is fix the HTML, it weren't really right.

HTML:

```
<nav > 
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><img src="image/language.png" alt="English - UK" width="229" height="37" /></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="HTML.html"><img src="image/english.png" alt="English - UK" width="139" height="37" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="image/portugues.png" alt="Portugues - BR" width="139" height="37" /></a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78uU6/)

I think your problem is the way your entire website positions, not just the dropdown menu.

Edit: You just changed your HTML to exactly the same I did, my bad cause I seen it after you updated it.

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
 nav ul ul {
   display: none;
}


 nav ul li:hover ul {
     display: inline;
}

nav ul {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 300px 50px;        
    margin-left: -10px; 
padding: 10px;    
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline; 
bottom: 100%;

}

nav ul:after {
    content: "";
}   

    nav ul li {
    float: left;

}

nav ul li:hover {


}

nav ul li:hover a {
/*color: #fff;*/
}

nav ul li a {
 padding: 0px;
}

nav ul ul {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 139px 37px;

padding: 1px;   
}

nav ul ul li {
float: none;        
position: relative;   
    display:inline;
}

nav ul ul li a {
padding: 0 10px;
/*color: #fff;*/
}   

nav ul ul li a:hover {

}

nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:50;
}
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2uPEs/7/)

Comment: it work in JSfiddle but when i change my codes the menu goes to down and to the left. Dont know why.